# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object] while exporting a function

Tags: node.js, express, compiler-errors

I want to export this function and use this this as a middleware for using socket.io on multiple routes. The socket.io initialization needs the server instance that is why I am writing this in my app.js and not in a Middleware file.
I am exporting the function correctly I think but still the post route is giving me this error. I am exporting a function not an object.

This is the code for app.js

```
//in app.js
const io = socketIO(server);

function useSocketIO(req, res, next) {
  io.on("connect", (socket) => {
    console.log("listening to events");
    req.socket = socket;
  });

  req.io = io;
  console.log("hi bitch");
  next();
}

module.exports = { useSocketIO };
```

And this is how I am using it in the route

```
const useSocketIO = require("../../app");
routes.post("/pay", authCheck, useSocketIO, async (req, res) => {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you exported `useSocketIO` as a prop of the default export object you need to access it through the imported object instead of assuming the object itself is the `useSocketIO`:

```js
const { useSocketIO } = require("../../app");
routes.post("/pay", authCheck, useSocketIO, async (req, res) => {...}
// or
const app = require("../../app");
routes.post("/pay", authCheck, app.useSocketIO, async (req, res) => {...}
```

Comment: still not working. Instead it is giving [object undefined] instead of [object Object]. I tried that before. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Did you check `authCheck` as well?

Comment: And I created the similar `app.js` (with empty `useSocketIO` function) and it works just fine.